# ¿Como reenviar un dato de una tabla a otra?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de registrar una información de un producto a una tabla MySQL haciendo click sobre una tabla que esta siendo imprimida por medio de un echo pero no logro captar el valor de las variables.

con este código estoy imprimiendo los productos:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fruteria";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM frutas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$table = '
<table border=1 class="productos">
    <tr>
        <td>IMAGEN</td>
        <td>NOMBRE</td>
        <td>PRECIO</td>
        <td>CANTIDAD</td>
</tr>
';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $table .= '
    <tr>

        <td class="imagen"> <img src="'.$row["imagen"].'"></td>
        <td class="nombre">'.$row["nombre"].'</td>
        <td class="precio">'.$row["precio"].'</td>
        <td class="cantidad">'.$row["cantidad"].'</td>
        <td><button><a href="datos2.php">comprar</a></button></td>
    </tr>
';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
}
?>
```

y con este me encuentro tratando de capturar el producto para enviarla a otra tabla MySQL:

```
<?php

$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fruteria";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO compras (imagen, nombre, precio, cantidad)
VALUES ('$imagen', '$nombre', '$precio', '$cantidad')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Intente usar el "this" al momento de crear las variables pero no daba resultado ya que me arroja que las variables no existen.

Comment: No queda muy clara tu pregunta. Si pones todo el código de tus archivos será más fácil encontrar el problema. Al margen, `$this->var` se usa dentro de una clase y no es tu caso.

Comment: me parece que te falta darnos parte del codigo de js, pero supongo que lo estaras haciendo con jquery, tendrias que usar isset($_POST['imagen']) y asi con todas las variables, ponele atributos a el boton que presoinas asi será mas facil obtener los datos, igualmente deberias indicarnos el error que sale o la forma en la que tomas los datos desde el front